# Could the star on favorited questions change in color?

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

I think it would be nice if the star you put on favourite questions would change in colour, just like a comment does as it get more and more up votes.

It could go from a grey outline (like it is today), to an actual golden star.

Comment: Wouldn't that require a huge number of "star" bitmaps?

Comment: I think the comment number only have like 4 different colours. *cool*, *warm*, *hot* and *supernova* or something like that.

Comment: This question got me wondering about the design choices behind the color-coding. So I asked [a new question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97063/whats-the-deal-with-color-coding-of-comment-votes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would be problematic, since the star already changes color when you favorite and unfavorite.

Comment: Favourite is a state that only you see the star in.  You could keep the same star for favoured (as only you see it) and change the outline when you see the unfavoured version, based on number of favourites?

Comment: Oh, you're right. I never favoured a question before so I hadn't noticed that. Just wanted to bring some more color into an already well designed site. But if there's no way around that, never mind =)

Comment: To <del>be argumentative</del> <ins>play devil's advocate for the good of the network</ins>, comment arrows never change color; only the scores do. This request could be handled similarly.

Answer (score 3):

As **@Popular Demand** mentioned in a comment. If the star stay the same then the number under the star could go from grey to gold instead. Which would be coherent with the way comment's score change in color.

Comment: Based on the premise that [a UI should be consistent](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/6576/3612), I agree.

Answer (score 2):

Not an artist here, but perhaps six stars (or a clever use of transparency) could be used to display both indicators using a single icon.

[image]

Comment: Cool idea, but might be hard to make it look good with all of the various Stack Exchange site themes

Answer (score 2):

Yes I would go with something like this:
[image: new star outline colors]

Changing the star "border" can give it more meaning and look cooler to my eyes. :)